# iOS keypad close after leaving the textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have to focus on a UItextfield when I enter on screen.I use the following code for this:

[textfield becomefirstresponder]

This works fine.

I have several UItextfields on that screen. Once I tap on the other textfield , the focus should shift on that UItextfield and the keyboard for the earlier textfield should first close and then reappear for second textfield.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use resignFirstResponder on the first field and then becomeFirstResponder on the next one